# Designing an alien spore that's deadly to humans with the ability to wipe out billions

Tags: science-based, xenobiology, biochemistry

I'm working on creating a post-apocalyptic world brought on by a deadly alien organism. The organism by itself is not that threatening - it's pretty much a small lump of slime with legs. However, it gives off a spore that's extremely deadly to humans. Maybe in its home planet, this spore is used for something else - let's say communication with other slimes. But it's not so friendly to humans. Let's handwave a little (a lot) and assume that transfer from alien to human is possible.

Let's aim for, say, 60-70% of the human population to be infected and die. The resulting chaos, from the rotting bodies, failure of infrastructure, widespread violence etc. should take care of the rest.

Now I'm aware of some of the properties the spore/virus would need to have, i.e. being airborne, extremely contagious, longer incubation period, initial mild symptoms etc. And being so alien and unfamiliar, maybe we just can't figure out a vaccine in time.

What I'm looking for is the actual mechanics through which the spore could infect and kill. i.e. what could it *do* exactly, to our bodies on the inside, that gives it all the properties above and ends up with it killing us?

Comment: Are you requiring an *infection*? Or are other causes of mortality like poisoning permissible? You can get broad-area effects by having the agent/spore retain toxicity when suspended in water, poisoning an entire city or region...and then the next city downstream, too.

Comment: @user535733 doesn't have to be an infection necessarily. Anything is fine, I just want the results. The poisoning of an entire region sounds pretty cool.

Comment: Consider editing your question, which repeatedly uses infection-related language.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how dark you want to be and how much time you want it to take.

Slow?  It's HIV.

Fast?  It's "The Stand".

Zombie?  At the end the human goes insane and attacks everyone.

You have a host animal so it's not going away, it can be airborne as well as person to person.  You're seriously into bio-weapon territory.

Answer (score 1):

Make it look like a fat cell, and have the alien reproduce through polips that form on their surface where a spore lands and merges with another cell that looks like a fat cell. Normally it would drop off once it reaches a certain size (say the size of an 8 week old fetus) and most of them don't survive to gain sentience as they get eaten by the wildlife. But humans keep their fat cells inside, so if the person is really lucky, then they die slowly by having all their fat stores co-opted (treatment is possible), otherwise the polip enters the blood stream causing a heart attack or brain bleed. For the really unlucky ones a spore makes it to the brain (which is mostly fat) and grows there.

The reason the body doesn't recognise it as a pathogen is because it looks like it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that alien means *extra-terrestrial* here.

With this assumptions, a virus is not a plausible candidate because a virus uses the genetical enginge of the host cell to replicate. For extra-terrrestrial life it is very improbable to have a compatible genetical engine (see also this answer on incompatibilities in life forms: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/123667/19004 )

So it is more like a bacterium or a fungus, starting to feed on human cells and producing more spores. This feeding alone can already be very dangerous when our immune system cannot cope with the invader. To make it worse, the invader may produce some chemically simple substance that is toxic to humans but not to the invader, as a candidate toxin I suggest [BMAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-Methylamino-L-alanine).

Answer (score 0):

I'm shamelessly recycling answers, but I suggested these for another plague question and they're even more apt here.Make the symptoms resemble those of a known deadly disease, so people assume it's terrestrial and you'll have known routes of infection, patterns of behavior, ect.to copy when you have questions. First:

Fever.

Headache.

Nausea.

Vomiting.

Agitation.

Anxiety.

Confusion.

Hyperactivity.

Fear of water.

A disease resembling an airborne version of rabies would be especially horrifying. Rabies affects the nervous system and spreads up from the infection site to the brain. It could result in extremely (almost 100%) high lethality to those who are infected (or anything less you desired) once you had symptoms and it would have a fairly large number of reservoirs amongst animals. Infected people would behave erratically as the virus invaded their nervous system. Give it a longer incubation period and a high mutation rate to make vaccines ineffective. I heard something like this suggested on a documentary as a possible zombie apocalypse substitution because of the behavioral changes. Nasty.

If this is too awful, anthrax IS a sporulated disease. Spores are virtually indestructible (supposedly, the test sites for anthrax from around WW1 are still uninhabitable due to the spores). A contact or aerosolized version would give you different vectors and patterns of spread. Inhalation anthrax is very lethal. Inhalation anthrax develops when you breathe in anthrax spores. It's the most deadly way to contract the disease, and even with treatment, it is often fatal. Incubation period for inhalation anthrax can be weeks. This is from the Mayo clinic

-https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/anthrax/symptoms-causes/syc-20356203 Initial signs and symptoms of inhalation anthrax include:

Flu-like symptoms, such as sore throat, mild fever, fatigue and muscle aches, which may last a few hours or days. Mild chest discomfort, Shortness of breath, Nausea Coughing up blood, Painful swallowing. As the disease progresses, you may experience:

High fever, Trouble breathing, Shock, and Meningitis.